# problem with nested inner joins in SQLIte

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

The sql statement below will not run in SQLite:

```
select * 
from A
left join (B inner join C on B.fkC = C.pk) on A.optionalfkB = B.pk
```

I get a sqlException "unknown column B.pk"

According to the documentation @ http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html this should work, and it will work in all other sql implementations. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have two options, but neither of which are very good for performance: use a nested sql expression, or just another left join between B and C. I don't like using left joins unless I have to though because I've found they take a LOT longer to execute

Comment: Could you perhaps post the schema of your tables (even if they are a sample)? that would really help in answering the question.

Comment: Are you trying to use a subquery like this? `select * from A left join (SELECT * FROM B inner join C on B.fkC = C.pk) subQ on A.optionalfkB = subQ.pk`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work because the "outer" query doesn't know what B is.

```
select * 
from A
left join (B inner join C on B.fkC = C.pk) B on A.optionalfkB = B.pk
```

The `(B inner join C on B.fkC = C.pk)` is weird without any `select`, but the specification does say that it is valid.

Comment: You are a legend! thank you! I couldn't find a solution to this anywhere and you nailed it.

Comment: @stitty You were still on this issue 2 years after asking the question? haha, glad I could help!