# SQL query with inner join using SQLite in a python pyqt program where I get "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a program that I'm creating with PyQt4 and a backend database with SQLite. I'm trying to display a table. So I needed an Inner Join with my database.
The code I have is:

```
c.execute("SELECT tblStudents.StudentID, tblStudents.Forename, tblStudents.Surname, tblTestType.Name, tblTests.Score, tblTests.AmountTried, tblTeachers.Initials FROM tblTestType INNER JOIN (tblTeachers INNER JOIN ((tblStudents INNER JOIN tblClasses ON tblStudents.StudentID = tblClasses.StudentID) INNER JOIN tblTests ON tblStudents.StudentID = tblTests.StudentID) ON tblTeachers.TeacherID = tblClasses.TeacherID) ON tblTestType.TypeID = tblTests.TypeID;")
    data = c.fetchall()
    print(data)
    for i,row in enumerate(data):
        for j,val in enumerate(row):
            self.table.setItem(i, j, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(val)))
```

And The error I get is:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: tblStudents.StudentID
```

Please could you help me. If I haven't given enough information I can give you more. Thank you!

EDIT:
".schema tblStudents" gives me:

```
CREATE TABLE tblStudents
(
StudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Forename TEXT(30),
Surname TEXT(30),
Login TEXT(32),
Password TEXT(20),
YearJoined INTEGER
);
```

EDIT 2:
I found a similar question: [problem with nested inner joins in SQLIte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071283/problem-with-nested-inner-joins-in-sqlite)
and with the edited sql line here:

```
SELECT tblStudents.StudentID, tblStudents.Forename, tblStudents.Surname, tblTestType.Name, tblTests.Score, tblTests.AmountTried, tblTeachers.Initials 
FROM tblStudents, tblClasses, tblTestType, tblTests, tblTeachers 
INNER JOIN (tblTeachers INNER JOIN ((tblStudents INNER JOIN tblClasses ON tblStudents.StudentID = tblClasses.StudentID) 
INNER JOIN tblTests ON tblStudents.StudentID = tblTests.StudentID) ON tblTeachers.TeacherID = tblClasses.TeacherID) ON tblTestType.TypeID = tblTests.TypeID 
ORDER BY tblStudents.StudentID ASC;
```

I'm getting a new error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: tblClasses.TeacherID
```

The schema for tblClasses is:

```
CREATE TABLE tblClasses
(
ClassID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
StudentID INTEGER,
TeacherID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES tblStudents(StudentID),
FOREIGN KEY (TeacherID) REFERENCES tblTeachers(TeacherID)
);
```

EDIT 3:
If I input the first query  directly into SQLite3 it says "A JOIN clause is required before ON".

EDIT 4:
I now under stand the other question more and changed it but it hasn't made any effect

```
SELECT tblStudents.StudentID, tblStudents.Forename, tblStudents.Surname, tblTestType.Name, tblTests.Score, tblTests.AmountTried, tblTeachers.Initials 
FROM tblTestType 
INNER JOIN (tblTeachers INNER JOIN ((tblStudents INNER JOIN tblClasses ON tblStudents.StudentID = tblClasses.StudentID) tblStudents 
INNER JOIN tblTests ON tblStudents.StudentID = tblTests.StudentID) tblClasses ON tblTeachers.TeacherID = tblClasses.TeacherID) tblTests ON tblTestType.TypeID = tblTests.TypeID 
ORDER BY tblStudents.StudentID DESC;
```

Comment: The table might be there, but sqlite complains about the StudentID column being missing. Can you run `sqlite3 database-file`, and execute `.schema tblStudents`, and add the output to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the SQL was simpler than I thought.
The SQL is:

```
SELECT tblStudents.StudentID, 
tblStudents.Forename, 
tblStudents.Surname, 
tblTestType.Name, 
tblTests.Score, 
tblTests.AmountTried, 
tblTeachers.Initials 
FROM tblTestType 
INNER JOIN tblTests 
ON tblTestType.TypeID = tblTests.TypeID 
INNER JOIN tblStudents 
ON tblStudents.StudentID = tblTests.StudentID
INNER JOIN tblClasses 
ON tblStudents.StudentID = tblClasses.StudentID 
INNER JOIN
tblTeachers ON tblTeachers.TeacherID = tblClasses.TeacherID
ORDER BY tblStudents.StudentID DESC;
```