# "SQL error or missing database (no such column" but table with column exists

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a local SQLite database where I put some CSV files into.

When running this query:

```
SELECT
      cc.codedname
    , cc.PreferredName
    , pr.IrdiPR
    , pr.identifier
    , pr.PreferredName
    , pr.datatype
    , pr.IrdiUN
    , un.﻿PreferredName
    , restricted_values.IrdiCC
    , restricted_values.IrdiPR
    , restricted_values.IrdiVA
    , restricted_values.preferredname_va
    , pr.definition
--
FROM
    (cc
    INNER JOIN (pr
                INNER JOIN (cc_pr
                            LEFT JOIN restricted_values
                                   ON  (
                                   cc_pr.IrdiPR = restricted_values.IrdiPR
                                   AND cc_pr.IrdiCC = restricted_values.﻿IrdiCC
                                   )
                            )
                ON pr.IdPR = cc_pr.IdPR
                )
   ON cc.IdCC = cc_pr.IdCC
   )
   LEFT JOIN un
   ON pr.IrdiUN = un.IrdiUN
```

I get this error in DBeaver:

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: restricted_values.﻿IrdiCC)

But the table "restricted_values" does exist and has a column named "﻿IrdiCC"?

Comment: see if this helps (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071283/problem-with-nested-inner-joins-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

Write each `ON` clause after the join it belongs to and don't make excessive use of parentheses that make the code harder to read:

```
.....................................................................
FROM cc
INNER JOIN cc_pr ON cc.IdCC = cc_pr.IdCC
INNER JOIN pr ON pr.IdPR = cc_pr.IdPR
LEFT JOIN un ON pr.IrdiUN = un.IrdiUN
LEFT JOIN restricted_values ON cc_pr.IrdiPR = restricted_values.IrdiPR 
                           AND cc_pr.IrdiCC = restricted_values.﻿IrdiCC
```